# MIGS Integeration Error - Invalid Digital Order

Tags: java, php, content-management-system, e-commerce, payment-gateway

I need to integrate my application with MIGS, But when I call the URLfor DO (Digital Order) 3-party payment:

```
https://migs.mastercard.com.au/vpcpay?vpc_Version=1&vpc_Command=pay&vpc_AccessCode=A1E5316C&vpc_Merchant=UPSKWT&vpc_MerchTxnRef=1234xxx&vpc_OrderInfo=1234xxx&vpc_Amount=500&vpc_Locale=en&vpc_ReturnURL=&vpc_SecureHash=7249c9ecc97b373c0743d1740dc18ac7
```

I get the error:

> "**W5001-09081744: Invalid Digital Order**"

as this screenshot:

[image: this is my error]

Please anyone, support me.

Comment: There appears to be a [magento.se] site, which [offers this solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90140/invalid-digital-order-migs-payment-gateway).

Comment: I am facing with same issue. Kindly help me any solution

Answer (score 1):

It is because your Order number is already in the system it is duplicating send new OrderInfo (whatever your variable name is)